# подскажите, почему последний вызов выдает undefined, хотя должен отрабатывать...не пойму

Tags: javascript

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr){
    var elS,elF,arrF,arrS;

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

         arrF = arr.slice(0, arr[i]);
         arrS = arr.slice(arr[i] + 1, arr.length);

         elF = 0;
         for (var j = 0; j < arrF.length; j++){
             elF += arrF[j];
         }

         elS = 0;
        for (var v = 0; v < arrS.length; v++){
            elS += arrS[v];
        }


        //console.log(elF);
        //console.log(elS);

        if(elF == elS){
            return arr[i];
        }
    }

}

console.log(findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1])); //3
console.log(findEvenIndex([1,100,50,-51,1,1])); //1
console.log(findEvenIndex([50,60,70,80,70,60,50])); //3
```

Comment: а что делает этот код?

Comment: Может потому что `elF` не равно `elS`? Добавьте условие *или*

Comment: очевидно условие `elF == elS` никогда не выполняется и так как отсутствует другой `return` - значение вызова функции _undefined_

Comment: нужно найти элемент в массиве где сумма до него и после элементов равны

Comment: @Yuri if( (elF равно elS) или (elF не равно elS) ) {  } ?

Comment: но первые два вызова отрабатываю почему тогда?

Comment: @lesha310392, у вас в третьем `elF` не равно `elS`

Comment: @lesha310392 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Товарищ! Используй `Array.prototype.slice` правильно!

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

```
 arrF = arr.slice(0, i);
 arrS = arr.slice(i + 1, arr.length);
```

Comment: а можно объяснить?

Comment: @L.Vadim в комментарии к вопросу уже скинули: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice.  
Используя `arrF = arr.slice(0, arr[i]);` Вы получаете массив с нулевого элемента и длинной, которая хранится в i-том элементе массива arr.   Вам же надо обрезать i элементов, поэтому и надо использовать `arrF = arr.slice(0, i);`